# Will this malloc the second structure?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc, structure

Will `p = (users *)malloc(sizeof(users));` create memory for the playlist structure too? Also how can I reference playlist.album using p?

```
struct playlist_ {
  int album;
  int track_num;
  struct playlist_ *next;
};

struct users_ {
  int user_ID;
  struct playlist_ playlist;
  struct users_ *next;
};

typedef struct playlist_  playlists;
typedef struct users_ users;

users *p;
p = (users *)malloc(sizeof(users));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982339/malloc-of-struct-array-with-varying-size-structs

Not  your question, but has some good examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will `p = (users *)malloc(sizeof(users));` create memory for the playlist structure too?

`playlist` is a member of `users_`, so it forms part of the allocated space.  So to answer your question: yes.

*[Incidentally, you don't need to (and shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`.]*

> Also how can I reference playlist.album using p?

Depends what you mean by "reference".  Assuming you just mean "access", then this:

```
p->playlist.album
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. `struct users_` contains an *instance* of `struct playlist_` so allocating memory for the former will reserve room for the latter too.

On the other hand, if `struct users_` contained a *pointer* to `struct playlist_` you'd have to allocate memory for the latter after allocating memory for the former.

To reference `playlist.album` use `p->playlist.album`